# One parameter subgroup on a Lie group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\{\psi_t\}$ a one-parameter subgroup of $G$ (i.e. $\psi:\mathbb R\times G\to G$ a smooth map, $\psi(t,\cdot):G\to G$ diffeomorphism, $\psi(0,\cdot)=\text{id}_G$, and $\psi(t,\cdot)\circ \psi(s,\cdot)=\psi(s+t,\cdot)$). Is true that $\psi(\mathbb R\times \{e\})$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I can't prove that the internal operation $\cdot$ of $G$ is also internal on $\psi(\mathbb R\times \{e\}$; thas is: $\forall t,s\in\mathbb R$ there exists $r\in \mathbb R$ s.t. $\psi_t(e)\cdot\psi_s(e)=\psi_r(e)$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, $\psi(\mathbb R \times \{e\})$ is non-empty, because $e=\text{id}_G(e)=\psi(0,e)\in \psi(\mathbb R \times \{e\})$.

Furthermore, $\psi(\mathbb R \times \{e\})$ is closed under the operation $\cdot$ of $G$, because 
$$
\psi(s,e)\cdot \psi(t,e)=\psi(s+t,e)\in \psi(\mathbb R \times \{e\})
$$
for all $s,t\in\mathbb R$.

The last thing you need to check are inverses: For $g=\psi(s,e)\in\psi(\mathbb R \times \{e\})$ you have
$$
\psi(s,e)\cdot\psi(-s,e)=\psi(0,e)=\text{id}_G(e)=e,
$$
hence $g^{-1}=\psi(-s,e)\in\psi(\mathbb R \times \{e\})$.

Comment: Why $\psi(s,e)\cdot \psi(t,e)=\psi(s+t,e)$? We only have says that $\psi(s,\cdot)\circ\psi(t,\cdot)=\psi(s+t,\cdot)$